# ImportError: cannot import name weave

Tags: python, scipy

This error shows when I run my script and it never showed before. I wonder if it's a problem of version.

If I type

```
python -c "from scipy import weave; print weave._path_"
```

then it gives

> File "", line 1, in module 
>   ImportError: cannot import name weave

Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: have you installed `scipy`?

Comment: The `weave` package in scipy had been deprecated for quite a while, and was removed from scipy in version 0.19.0: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.0.19.0.html#backwards-incompatible-changes; see the answer by Zach Gates if you need `weave`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser This helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You need to install `weave`; it became a separate project.

[`pip install weave`](https://github.com/scipy/weave)